# Pass props from page to components in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to pass my props from a page to all other components. I have a dynamic route set up like this.

```
-pages
  -[tv]
  -index.js
   -category
   -index.js
   ...
```

So the rout looks like this: pages/[tv]/category/...

My index.js, child of folder [tv], page code.

```
const Home = props => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { tv } = router.query
  console.log(tv) //Value that i want to pass as props to other components.
```

So i want to pass value of tv to other components as props.
Hope my question is not too vague.

Thank you

Comment: Which are the other componentd?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Other components are children pages of the [tv] folder. That is the only connection between them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If those components are rendered in `Home` component, you can just pass `tv` as prop:

```
const SomeComponent = props => {
  const { query } = useRouter()
  const { tv } = query
  // ...
}

const Home = props => {
  // ...

  return (
    <SomeComponent />
  )
};
```

If you don't want prop drilling then you can just use the `useRouter` hook.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The components that i want to pass the props are not nested inside of the page `Home` page. Is there a way of passing them similar as react context?

Comment: Yes, just like you are using `useRouter` in Home you can use it in some other component as well. next/router shares context with whole react tree.

Comment: So i can use `useRouter` in any component to pass the value from `Home` page? Any code example would be gold at this point :)

Comment: You don't need to pass it using prop. I've edited my answer. You can read more [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes).

Comment: It's weird because it isn't actually a query variable but rather a path variable; query parameters are usually what comes behind the question mark.